# Why javascript setTimeout does all at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've got this code and I don't know why all the functions in the loop are called at once!

```
this.line = function($l) {
    var $this = this;
    $this.$len = 0;
    $('.active').hide(0,function(){             
        $this.$len = $l.length;
        var j = 1;
        $.each($l,function(i,item){
            var t = setTimeout(function(){
                $this._echoLine($l[i]);
                clearTimeout(t);
                if (j >= $this.$len) $('.active').show();
                j++;
            },500*j);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you only increment `j` *inside* the timeout function, but the delay (which depends on `j`) is still `1` at the time the timeout handler is registered.

Seeing as you have a loop index variable anyway (`i`), try this:

```
$l.each(function(i, item) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this._echoLine($l[i]);
    }, 500 * (i + 1));
});

// a separate timeout to fire after all the other ones
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.active').show();
}, ($l.length + 1) * 500);
```

There's no need for the `clearTimeout` line, so no need to declare or store `t` either.

Comment: I need to be sure if the function in the timeout is called! How can I do that?

Comment: @XIII: What does this have to do with how quickly the timeouts are called? Maybe you should explain what you are *actually* trying to do. Asking for a solution to a problem is often better than asking for a solution to a solution.

Comment: I need to call a queue of functions one after another and I can't use callbacks.

Comment: @XIII why can't you use callbacks?  That's the _only_ way to trigger an action for "later" in Javascript.  Your existing code is using callbacks anyway!

Comment: It's a kind of animation. But in my code, it all runs in the same time!

Comment: 'if (i >= $this.$len) $('.active').show(); ' This just runs before the timeouts! I need it to be after them!

Comment: @XIII no, it's running _during_ each of the timeouts.  If you want it to run only after _all_ the timeouts have expired then that's a different problem.

Comment: That's it! How can i do that?

Comment: @XIII please see edits...  and next time be sure to be clearer in your question.  We had no way of knowing that the `.show()` line was supposed to be run last.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works.

```
this.line = function($l) {
    var $this = this;
    $this.$len = 0;
    $('.active').hide(0,function(){             
        $this.$len = $l.length;
        var j = 1;
        $.each($l,function(i,item){
            var t = setTimeout(function(){
                $this._echoLine($l[i]);
                clearTimeout(t);
                if (j >= $this.$len) $('.active').show();
                j++;
            });
        });
    });
}

setTimeout(function() { this.line(); }, 500);
```

Comment: You don't pass any time to the inner timeout... on purpose?

Comment: I don't understand this concept!

Comment: @XIII don't worry, it's not just you.  this code doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. i edited the code. Set timeout to main function, so it should fix your issue.

Comment: @zonf no, it still won't work.  Per Felix's comment, you never set a timeout on the _inner_ call to `setTimeout`.